# How To Access CommandParameter value from View Model

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, telerik

I have a Button in the view:

```
<Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Content="Export to CSV "  
        HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Margin="2,2,20,2" Style="{StaticResource ExportButton}"
        Command="{Binding ExportToExcelCommand}"
        CommandParameter="{TelerikGrid}"
/>
```

Now I have the `ExportCommand` in my `ViewModel` as :

```
private RelayCommand _exportToExcelCommand;
public ICommand ExportToExcelCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_exportToExcelCommand == default(RelayCommand))
        {
            _exportToExcelCommand = new RelayCommand(ExportToExcel, CanExport);
        }
        return _exportToExcelCommand;
    }
}

private void ExportToExcel(Object param)
{
    try
    {
        //ToDo: Update With Command Parameters
        RadGridView gdv = new RadGridView();

        using (Stream stream = dialog.OpenFile())
        {
            gdv.Export(Columns);
        }
    }
    catch (FaultException ex)
    {
        var faultMessage = ex.Reason.GetMatchingTranslation().Text + "/n" + ex.StackTrace;
    }
}
```

Now I am creating a new instance of RadGridView:

```
RadGridView gdv = new RadGridView();
```

But instead I want to assign `gdv` from the value that is passed as `CommandParameter` from XAML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RadGridView gdv = (RadGridView)param;
```

`param` is the object you sent, so just cast it to its origin.